# calling python function in Q

Tags: python, kdb

trying to work with the result of a python function call in q as described in https://code.kx.com/v2/ml/embedpy/userguide/#function-calls
they give this example:

```
q)np:.p.import`numpy
q)np`:arange
{[f;x]embedPy[f;x]}[foreign]enlist
q)arange:np`:arange                   / callable returning embedPy
q)arange 12
{[f;x]embedPy[f;x]}[foreign]enlist
q)arange[12]`
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
q)arange_py:.p.pycallable np`:arange / callable returning foreign
q)arange_py 12
foreign
q)arange_q:.p.qcallable np`:arange   / callable returning q
q)arange_q 12
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

but when i run this code in KxAnalyst I don't get the results, I get "foreign" as return type:

```
q)np:.p.import`numpy
{[f;x]embedPy[f;x]}[foreign]enlist
q)arange:np`:arange  
{[f;x]embedPy[f;x]}[foreign]enlist
q)arange[12]`
foreign
```

or again:

```
q)arange_q:.p.qcallable np`:arange  
code.[code[foreign]]`.p.q2pargsenlist
q)arange_q 12
foreign
```

so maybe i'm missing something but it looks like kdb doesn't behave the way it's described in the doc.
any idea?

Best,

Comment: What version of kdb+ are you running in Analyst? 

Can you try running q)print arange_q 12

Comment: .Q.k displays 3.6 yes, print arange_q 12 does display the list. ok so is it that basically my object is not converted, it is wrapped in an EmbedPy q object, but really I have to write a function to convert whatever the object is in a q object, basically parse my python list and build a q list from it?

Comment: No you shouldn't have to do that I don't think (although that may work), what you're suggesting in the question in the first code cell should work, it seems there's a clash somewhere in your building of the system... Are you running a version of python >=3.5?

Comment: running 3.6. well yesterday my session got corrupted, lost all my work, support resetted something, I created a new session, and now said examples are behaving correctly. So not sure what was the underlying cause but at least now problem solved: code was correct. Thanks a lot for the hints Cmccarthy1!